# Looping actions between two folders and matching files

Tags: excel, vba

I am basically a beginner in VBA and I am stuck in a rut at the moment. I can't figure out how to automatize this procedure:
I have two different folders, with the same amount of files. Files name are pretty the same (they change like by 3 letters, but they have a numeric count e.i. AAA_Test18 in folder_A and BBB_Test18 in folder_B)
I need to modify (adding a tab to file in folder_b of the corresponding file in folder_A) all the files in the folder_B matching the number of the file in the folder_A.
I already have the code that does everything I need on a single file but the point is that I have to open every single file, get the test number from the user and repeat it for each test number.
Do you know how to loop it?

Heres the code

```
    Sub NoLoop()

Dim oFoglio As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim Count As Integer
Dim Tcount As Integer
Dim FileName As String
Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim iVal As Integer
Dim FN As String
Dim NewPath As String
Dim strFileName As String
Dim FileName2 As String
Dim FNumber As String

strFileName = Dir("C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Folder\COMPARE\*1.xlsx")


Do While Len(strFileName) > 0

Set oFoglio = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
oFoglio.Name = "COMPARE2"


Set wkb = ActiveWorkbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  
Set closedBook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Folder\DPP\Esempio_DPP_Report_v" & FNumber & ".xlsx")
    closedBook.Sheets("DPP").Copy Before:=wkb.Sheets(1)
    closedBook.Close savechanges:=False
  
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


Count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("DPP").Range("C:C")) + 1
Columns("J").Delete

For i = 3 To Count

Sheets("COMPARE").Cells(i, 1).Value = Sheets("DPP").Cells(i, 7).Value & Sheets("DPP").Cells(i, 8).Value & Sheets("DPP").Cells(i, 9).Value & Sheets("DPP").Cells(i, 10).Value
Sheets("COMPARE").Cells(i, 2).Value = Sheets("CQ").Cells(i, 7).Value & Sheets("CQ").Cells(i, 8).Value & Sheets("CQ").Cells(i, 9).Value & Sheets("CQ").Cells(i, 10).Value
Sheets("COMPARE").Cells(i, 3).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(FIND(""A"",RC[-2])),ISNUMBER(FIND(""A"",RC[-1]))),""NA"",IF(EXACT(RC[-2],RC[-1]),(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(""C"",RC[-2])),""TP"",""TN"")),(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(""C"",RC[-2])),""FP"",""FN""))))"

Sheets("COMPARE").Cells(i, 4).Value = Sheets("DPP").Cells(i, 11).Value & Sheets("DPP").Cells(i, 12).Value & Sheets("DPP").Cells(i, 13).Value & Sheets("DPP").Cells(i, 14).Value
Sheets("COMPARE").Cells(i, 5).Value = Sheets("CQ").Cells(i, 11).Value & Sheets("CQ").Cells(i, 12).Value & Sheets("CQ").Cells(i, 13).Value & Sheets("CQ").Cells(i, 14).Value
Sheets("COMPARE").Cells(i, 6).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(FIND(""A"",RC[-2])),ISNUMBER(FIND(""A"",RC[-1]))),""NA"",IF(EXACT(RC[-2],RC[-1]),(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(""C"",RC[-2])),""TP"",""TN"")),(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(""C"",RC[-2])),""FP"",""FN""))))"

Sheets("COMPARE").Cells(i, 7).Value = Sheets("DPP").Cells(i, 15).Value & Sheets("DPP").Cells(i, 16).Value
Sheets("COMPARE").Cells(i, 8).Value = Sheets("CQ").Cells(i, 15).Value & Sheets("CQ").Cells(i, 16).Value
Sheets("COMPARE").Cells(i, 9).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(FIND(""A"",RC[-2])),ISNUMBER(FIND(""A"",RC[-1]))),""NA"",IF(EXACT(RC[-2],RC[-1]),(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(""C"",RC[-2])),""TP"",""TN"")),(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(""C"",RC[-2])),""FP"",""FN""))))"

Sheets("COMPARE").Cells(i, 11).Value = Sheets("DPP").Cells(i, 2).Value
Sheets("COMPARE").Cells(i, 12).Value = Sheets("CQ").Cells(i, 2).Value
Sheets("COMPARE").Cells(i, 13).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=EXACT(RC[-2],RC[-1])"

Next i

'Bunch of other stuff to do by the code    
    
strFileName = Dir() 'moves on to check the next file
Loop

End Sub
```

It works but only for the first one of the folder...

Many Thanks

Comment: "I already have the code that does everything I need on a single file" - always helps to post the code you have.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, you should post what code you've already tried so people can point out where you need to improve.

Based on your question here are a few tips that might help though:

The `Dir` function, which you might already be using, is what you need to look for files and folders.

- See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dir-function) for the microsoft documentation on it.
- It can be called with [wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/wildcard-characters-used-in-string-comparisons) which allow for variation; for example the function. `Dir(C:\FolderPath\MyFolder\*.xlsx)` would return the file name of the first file in `Myfolder` with the file extension .xlsx, because the `*` wildcard allows for any characters in between the folder path and that file extension.
  In your case you might use this to find any files ending with a certain test number or something (don't forget the file extension afterward!)
- Calling the Dir function again with no arguments (just `Dir()`) finds the next filename in the same folder matching the original criteria. This is how you can loop through file names in a folder.

You'll also need A `Do While` or `Do Until` Loop - just google 'do until loop vba' and you'll find plenty of tutorials on how to put one together.

Rough Example:

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
Dim strFileName as String

strFileName = Dir("C:\Users\Me\Documents\MyFolder\*1.txt")
    'That's looking for a text file in MyFolder with a name ending in 1

    'The dir function returns an empty string if it doesn't find anything


Do While Len(strFileName) > 0 'Checking it hasn't returned an empty string
    '-------
    Debug.print strFileName
    'Do stuff to the file in this bit!
    '-------
    strFileName = Dir() 'moves on to check the next file
Loop


Msgbox "All files checked. :)", vbOkOnly + vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I tried also with the Dir function but the problem is : How do I cycle into the second folder where I need to pick a specific tab into each file and then put this tab into the other files folder, when I am cycling into the first folder? Also I need to transport the tab in the file which has the same test number has the originary tab's file.... Maybe taking into the Dir function the file name, extract the file number as a value and put like you show above (like "C:\Users\Me\Documents\MyOtherFolder\*" & myNumber & ".txt").   What do you think?

Comment: @IngegnerCane I'm afraid I don't really understand this second part of the question, and it would probably need a second question on stackoverflow rather than being answered here.